# MarkLogic - XDMP-HOSTOFFLINE: Host is offline or not responding

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, marklogic, hostname

MarkLogic 9.0.9
Deployed in Azure with Managed Disk

While setting up new MarkLogic Cluster, we are facing an issue for 2 server nodes as below

---

```
This host is down. The following error occurred while trying to contact it:
XDMP-HOSTOFFLINE: Host is offline or not responding

Host    <HostName>
Online  Disconnected
```

---

While looking at error log, I got this line

> 2020-05-06 05:22:28.832 Warning: A valid hostname is required for proper functioning of MarkLogic Server: SVC-SOCHN: Socket hostname error: getaddrinfo .reddog.microsoft.com: Name or service not known (where as it should connect to )

I got knowledge base article which is published in April 2020.
https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/svc-sochn-warning-during-start-up-on-aws

Based on this article, I do not find any file under `/etc/` or `/var/local` folders as mentioned in article

Not sure if it is because of this, I am not able to open MarkLogic Admin Interface (port 8001).

It seems that somewhere in the MarkLogic configuration this name is there, but which one is a question.

Please find below screen from host within MarkLogic Interface. In this case, disconnected status is for 01 & 03

Whereas I can access Admin Interface of 01, so I am wondering.

[image]

Comment: Quick guess: the hostname you used to specify the remote servers isn't resolving so the machines can't see each other. You've covered in blue the most applicable part of the screen capture. :)

Comment: Hello HH, thanks for your quick reply, As i can't disclose server names, so masked, Using same server name i have configured these server and added them to part of cluster, so that means it was resolved to machines and when i saw log file, "reddog.microsoft.com" added to name of machine, i don't know from where ML is getting this info.

Comment: Can you connect to each of the boxes and determine what each of them think their hostname is? Also, whether you can resolve the FQDN for the other hosts? Since you clustered these servers, something has changed either in the hostname resolution, whether ports are opened, or the IP that the names resolve to. If the FQDN of the hosts have changed, you may need to modify the config or drop them and re-couple.

Comment: Are you using the MarkLogic Solution Template for the Deployment or building your own hosts?  If the SVC-SOCHN error occurs immediately after boot up, then it can probably be ignored.  It does a dnslookup for the value of MARKLOGIC_HOST in /var/local/mlmcd.conf, and will not affect operation.

Comment: Hello MH, Thanks for your reply. I checked hostname for each box and they are same which are shown on screenshot i attached with masking. I can ping host name thru command line and it is giving pinged result. We have deployed MarkLogic using template available on Azure MarkPlace. And now unfortunately, same error for System Test environment from today and we have not touched System Test environment configuration in last 5 months. I am not able to browser to Admin interface of ST, it just not able to open any of port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing same issue with infra team, they found issue with DNS resolution as full dns was not set in hostname within MarkLogic.
i.e. ml-01 was set in hostname instead of ml-01.abc.com and then as MarkLogic was in azure, it added ml.01.**reddog.microsoft.com** automatically.

So outside MarkLogic we were able to ping server with full name.

After change in DNS resolution, i was able to add ML server nodes in cluster.

Comment: @Manish...Where can we set the hostname within MarkLogic. We are facing the same issue.

Comment: in ML Admin screen, expand configure option and under it you will find option to change hostname